# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de una llamada a Firebase para usarlo en un widget?

Tags: flutter, firestore, querystring

Quisiera tomar el valor de la variable nombre creada en la funcion de firestore y asignarla a una variable fuera de firestore y mostrarla en un text(nombre);

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Buenas, te ayudo si editas la pregunta y la dejas con un formato correcto. Te recomiendo leer los siguientes temas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Te informo que no deberías dar ejemplo de código mediante imagen, es mejor que escribas dicho código y lo coloques dentro de la etiqueta apropiada